# DataTable warning: table id=table - Ajax error(datatable.net/tn/7)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to make dynamic the data table in server side that I've found through the internet(for preference http://mbahcoding.com/tutorial/php/codeigniter/codeigniter-simple-server-side-datatable-example.html) because in this tutorial the table and the columns is fixed.

**Controller**

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('CrudModel');
        $this->load->model('AccountModel');
    $this->load->model('customers_model','customers');
    }
public function ajax_list()
  {
    // $list = $this->customers->get_datatables();
    $list = $this->AccountModel->get_datatables('customers'); //my table name
    $data = array();
    $no = $_POST['start'];
    foreach ($list as $customers) {
      $no++;
      $row = array();
      $row[] = $no;
      $row[] = $customers->FirstName;
      $row[] = $customers->LastName;
      $row[] = $customers->phone;
      $row[] = $customers->address;
      $row[] = $customers->city;
      $row[] = $customers->country;

      $data[] = $row;
    }

    $output = array(
            "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
            "recordsTotal" => $this->customers->count_all(),
            "recordsFiltered" => $this->customers->count_filtered(),
            "data" => $data,
        );
    //output to json format
    echo json_encode($output);
  }
```

The question is where $this->customers->count_all() and count_filtered() come from?

Comment: I believe you are following  [this](http://mbahcoding.com/tutorial/php/codeigniter/codeigniter-simple-server-side-datatable-example.html) example, 

Very simple code is there, just compare your code with that example and i promise your problem will be resolved by your self only. 
Because i have used that example  as well and its really working nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->customers->count_all() and count_filtered()
```

function came from your model

named

```
$this->load->model('customers_model','customers');
```

you should check your model in that, you can find this function

```
 function count_filtered()
{
    $this->_get_datatables_query();
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->num_rows();
}

public function count_all()
{
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```